# Query Optimization (WHERE, GROUP BY, LEFT JOINs)

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, left-join

I am using InnoDB.

**QUERY, EXPLAIN & INDEXES**

```
SELECT
  stories.*,
  count(comments.id) AS comments,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT classifications2.name SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS classifications_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT images.id
    ORDER BY images.position,
    images.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS images_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT images.caption
    ORDER BY images.position,
    images.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS images_caption,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT images.thumbnail 
    ORDER BY images.position,
    images.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS images_thumbnail,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT images.medium 
    ORDER BY images.position,
    images.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS images_medium,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT images.large 
    ORDER BY images.position,
    images.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS images_large,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT users.id 
    ORDER BY users.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS authors_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT users.display_name 
    ORDER BY users.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS authors_display_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT users.url 
    ORDER BY users.id SEPARATOR ';'
  ) AS authors_url
FROM
  stories 
  LEFT JOIN classifications 
    ON stories.id = classifications.story_id 
  LEFT JOIN classifications AS classifications2 
    ON stories.id = classifications2.story_id 
  LEFT JOIN comments
    ON stories.id = comments.story_id
  LEFT JOIN image_story 
    ON stories.id = image_story.story_id 
      LEFT JOIN images 
        ON images.id = image_story.`image_id` 
  LEFT JOIN author_story 
    ON stories.id = author_story.story_id 
      LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.id = author_story.author_id 
 WHERE classifications.`name` LIKE 'Home:Top%' 
   AND stories.status = 1
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY classifications.`name`, classifications.`position`

+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |      table       |  type  | possible_keys |   key    | key_len |          ref           |  rows  |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stories          | ref    | status        | status   |       1 | const                  | 434792 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classifications  | ref    | story_id      | story_id |       4 | stories.id             |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classifications2 | ref    | story_id      | story_id |       4 | stories.id             |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments         | ref    | story_id      | story_id |       8 | stories.id             |      6 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | image_story      | ref    | story_id      | story_id |       4 | stories.id             |      1 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | images           | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  |       4 | image_story.image_id   |      1 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | author_story     | ref    | story_id      | story_id |       4 | stories.id             |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  |       4 | author_story.author_id |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+

+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
|      Table      | Non_unique |  Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| stories         |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |      869584 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | created_at  |            1 | created_at  | A         |      434792 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | source      |            1 | source      | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | source_id   |            1 | source_id   | A         |      869584 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | type        |            1 | type        | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | status      |            1 | status      | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | type_status |            1 | type        | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| stories         |          1 | type_status |            2 | status      | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| classifications |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |         207 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| classifications |          1 | story_id    |            1 | story_id    | A         |         207 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| classifications |          1 | name        |            1 | name        | A         |         103 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| classifications |          1 | name        |            2 | position    | A         |         207 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| comments        |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |      239336 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| comments        |          1 | status      |            1 | status      | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| comments        |          1 | date        |            1 | date        | A         |      239336 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| comments        |          1 | story_id    |            1 | story_id    | A         |       39889 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
```

**QUERY TIMES**

It takes on average `0.035 seconds` to run.

If I remove only the `GROUP BY`, the time drops to `0.007` on average.

If I remove only the `stories.status=1` filter, the time drops to `0.025` on average. This one seems like it can be easily optimized.

And if I remove only the `LIKE` filter and `ORDER BY` clause, the time drops to `0.006` on average.

### UPDATE 1: 2013-04-13

My understanding has improved manifold going through the answers.

I added indices to `author_story` and `images_story` which seemed improved query to `0.025` seconds but for some strange reason the `EXPLAIN` plan looks a whole lot better. At this point removing `ORDER BY` drops query to `0.015` seconds and dropping both `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` improves query performance to `0.006`. I am these are the two things to focus on right now? I may move `ORDER BY` into app logic if needed.

Here are the revised `EXPLAIN` and `INDEXES`

```
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |      table       |  type  |          possible_keys          |   key    | key_len |           ref            | rows |                         Extra                          |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classifications  | range  | story_id,name                   | name     |     102 | NULL                     |   14 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stories          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,status                  | PRIMARY  |       4 | classifications.story_id |    1 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classifications2 | ref    | story_id                        | story_id |       4 | stories.id               |    1 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | author_story     | ref    | author_id,story_id,author_story | story_id |       4 | stories.id               |    1 | Using index condition                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY  |       4 | author_story.author_id   |    1 | Using where                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments         | ref    | story_id                        | story_id |       8 | stories.id               |    8 | Using where; Using index                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | image_story      | ref    | story_id,story_id_2             | story_id |       4 | stories.id               |    1 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | images           | eq_ref | PRIMARY,position_id             | PRIMARY  |       4 | image_story.image_id     |    1 | NULL                                                   |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+


+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
|      Table      | Non_unique |      Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| author_story    |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |      220116 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| author_story    |          0 | story_author       |            1 | story_id    | A         |      220116 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| author_story    |          0 | story_author       |            2 | author_id   | A         |      220116 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| author_story    |          1 | author_id          |            1 | author_id   | A         |        2179 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| author_story    |          1 | story_id           |            1 | story_id    | A         |      220116 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| image_story     |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |      148902 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| image_story     |          0 | story_image        |            1 | story_id    | A         |      148902 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| image_story     |          0 | story_image        |            2 | image_id    | A         |      148902 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| image_story     |          1 | story_id           |            1 | story_id    | A         |      148902 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| image_story     |          1 | image_id           |            1 | image_id    | A         |      148902 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| classifications |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |         257 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| classifications |          1 | story_id           |            1 | story_id    | A         |         257 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| classifications |          1 | name               |            1 | name        | A         |         128 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| classifications |          1 | name               |            2 | position    | A         |         257 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |      962570 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | created_at         |            1 | created_at  | A         |      481285 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | source             |            1 | source      | A         |           4 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | source_id          |            1 | source_id   | A         |      962570 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | type               |            1 | type        | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | status             |            1 | status      | A         |           4 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | type_status        |            1 | type        | A         |           2 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stories         |          1 | type_status        |            2 | status      | A         |           6 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| comments        |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |      232559 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| comments        |          1 | status             |            1 | status      | A         |           6 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| comments        |          1 | date               |            1 | date        | A         |      232559 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| comments        |          1 | story_id           |            1 | story_id    | A         |       29069 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| images          |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |      147206 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| images          |          0 | source_id          |            1 | source_id   | A         |      147206 | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| images          |          1 | position           |            1 | position    | A         |           4 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| images          |          1 | position_id        |            1 | id          | A         |      147206 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| images          |          1 | position_id        |            2 | position    | A         |      147206 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| users           |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |         981 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| users           |          0 | users_email_unique |            1 | email       | A         |         981 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+



SELECT
stories.*,
count(comments.id) AS comments,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users.id ORDER BY users.id SEPARATOR ';') AS authors_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users.display_name ORDER BY users.id SEPARATOR ';') AS authors_display_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users.url ORDER BY users.id SEPARATOR ';') AS authors_url,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT classifications2.name SEPARATOR ';') AS classifications_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.id ORDER BY images.position,images.id SEPARATOR ';') AS images_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.caption ORDER BY images.position,images.id SEPARATOR ';') AS images_caption,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.thumbnail ORDER BY images.position,images.id SEPARATOR ';') AS images_thumbnail,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.medium ORDER BY images.position,images.id SEPARATOR ';') AS images_medium,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.large ORDER BY images.position,images.id SEPARATOR ';') AS images_large
FROM
  classifications
  INNER JOIN stories
    ON stories.id = classifications.story_id 
  LEFT JOIN classifications AS classifications2 
    ON stories.id = classifications2.story_id 
  LEFT JOIN comments
    ON stories.id = comments.story_id
  LEFT JOIN image_story 
    ON stories.id = image_story.story_id 
  LEFT JOIN images 
    ON images.id = image_story.`image_id` 
 INNER JOIN author_story 
    ON stories.id = author_story.story_id 
 INNER JOIN users 
    ON users.id = author_story.author_id 
 WHERE classifications.`name` LIKE 'Home:Top%'
   AND stories.status = 1
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY NULL
```

### UPDATE 2: 2013-04-14

I noticed one other thing. If I don't SELECT `stories.content` (LONGTEXT) and `stories.content_html` (LONGTEXT) the query drops from `0.015` seconds to `0.006` seconds. For now I am considering if I can do without `content` and `content_html` or replace them with something else.

I have updated the query, indexes and explain in the 2013-04-13 update above instead of re-posting in this one since they were minor and incremental. The query is still using `filesort`. I can't get rid of `GROUP BY` but have gotten rid of `ORDER BY`.

### UPDATE 3: 2013-04-16

As requested, I dropped the stories_id INDEXES from both `image_story` and `author_story` as they are redundant. The result was that output of explain only changed to show that the `possible_keys` changed. It still didn't show `Using Index` optimization unfortunately.

Also changed `LONGTEXT` to `TEXT` and am now fetching `LEFT(stories.content, 500)` instead of `stories.content` which is making a very significant difference in query execution time.

```
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |      table       |  type  |        possible_keys        |     key      | key_len |           ref            | rows |                                Extra                                |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classifications  | ref    | story_id,name,name_position | name         |     102 | const                    |   10 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stories          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,status              | PRIMARY      |       4 | classifications.story_id |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classifications2 | ref    | story_id                    | story_id     |       4 | stories.id               |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | author_story     | ref    | story_author                | story_author |       4 | stories.id               |    1 | Using where; Using index                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY      |       4 | author_story.author_id   |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments         | ref    | story_id                    | story_id     |       8 | stories.id               |    8 | Using where; Using index                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | image_story      | ref    | story_image                 | story_image  |       4 | stories.id               |    1 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | images           | eq_ref | PRIMARY,position_id         | PRIMARY      |       4 | image_story.image_id     |    1 | NULL                                                                |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

innodb_buffer_pool_size
134217728

TABLE_NAME      INDEX_LENGTH
image_story     10010624
image_story     4556800
image_story     0

TABLE_NAME      INDEX_NAMES     SIZE
dawn/image_story    story_image     13921
```

Comment: Can you post the explain plan?

Comment: Show your indexes also.

Comment: what time do you expect to be good enough for the query?

Comment: @newtover, personally if it can hit under 0.01 seconds that would really put me at ease as this query can run a couple dozen times a second but that might be wishful thinking on my part. I'll take whatever I can get.

Comment: if the tables are not updated that frequently, the results of the query will be easily cached by the query cache and fetched almost instantly. Otherwise, I would store

Comment: @newtover, the table is updated very frequently as new stories keep coming. Freshness is important.

Comment: Is it possible to get a dump with test data? How about using paging for the results?

Comment: Does joining classifications twice help? It seems to me it'd be the same if you only joined it once. Also I've been told that doing a GROUP BY stories.id and SELECTing stories.* is discouraged because not all the stories columns are in the group by

Comment: Add the execution plan in the question. Can you try adding an index on `classifications (name, story_id)`?

Comment: why are you joining classifications twice?

Comment: I am joining classification twice because the one time I need to do a join the second time I need to do a group_concat on it. The group_concat has negligible impact, I tried removing it altogether to monitor it's impact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see two opportunities for optimization right away:

**Change an OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN**

Your query is currently scanning 434792 stories, and you should be able to narrow that down better, assuming not every story has a classification matching 'Home:Top%'.  It would be better to use an index to find the classifications you're looking for, and *then* look up the matching stories.

But you're using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for classifications, meaning all stories will be scanned whether they have a matching classification or not.  Then you're defeating that by putting a condition on classifications in the `WHERE` clause, effectively making it mandatory that there be a classification matching your pattern with `LIKE`.  So it's no longer an outer join, it's an inner join.

If you put the classifications table first, and make it an inner join, the optimizer will use that to narrow down the search for stories just to those that have a matching classification.

```
. . . 
FROM
  classifications
  INNER JOIN stories
    ON stories.id = classifications.story_id 
. . .
```

The optimizer is supposed to be able to figure out when it's advantageous to re-order tables, so you may not have to change the order in your query.  But you do need to use an `INNER JOIN` in this case.

**Add compound indexes**

Your intersection tables image_story and author_story don't have compound indexes.  It's often a big advantage to add compound indexes to the intersection tables in a many-to-many relationship, so that they can perform the join and get the "Using index" optimization.

```
ALTER TABLE image_story ADD UNIQUE KEY imst_st_im (story_id, image_id);
ALTER TABLE author_story ADD UNIQUE KEY aust_st_au (story_id, author_id);
```

---

Re your comments and update:

I'm not sure you created the new indexes correctly.  Your dump of the indexes doesn't show the columns, and according to the updated EXPLAIN, the new indexes aren't being used, which I would expect to happen.  Using the new indexes would result in "Using index" in the extra field of EXPLAIN, which should help performance.

Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table would be more complete information than a dump of the indexes (without column names) as you have shown.

You may have to run ANALYZE TABLE once on each of those tables after creating the indexes.  Also, run the query more than once, to make sure the indexes are in the buffer pool.  Is this table InnoDB or MyISAM?

I also notice in your EXPLAIN output that the `rows` column shows a lot fewer rows being touched.  That's an improvement.

Do you really need the `ORDER BY`?  If you use `ORDER BY NULL` you should be able to get rid of the "Using filesort" and that may improve performance.

---

Re your update:

You still aren't getting the "Using index" optimization from your `image_story` and `author_story` tables.  One suggestion I'd have is to eliminate the redundant indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE image_story DROP KEY story_id;
ALTER TABLE author_story DROP KEY story_id;
```

The reason is that any query that could benefit from the single-column index on story_id can also benefit from the two-column index on (story_id,image_id).  Eliminating the redundant index helps the optimizer make a better decision (as well as saving some space).  This is the theory behind a tool like [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html).

I'd also check to make sure your buffer pool is large enough to hold your indexes.  You don't want indexes to be paging in and out of the buffer pool during a query.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'
```

Check the size of indexes for your image_story table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'image_story';
```

And compare that to how much of those indexes are currently residing in the buffer pool:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT INDEX_NAME) AS INDEX_NAMES, SUM(DATA_SIZE) AS SIZE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '`test`.`image_story`' AND INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'
```

Of course, change `test` above to the database name your table belongs to.

That information_schema table is new in MySQL 5.6.  I assume you're using MySQL 5.6 because your EXPLAIN shows "Using index condition" which is also new in MySQL 5.6.

I don't use LONGTEXT at all unless I really need to story very long strings.  Keep in mind:

- TEXT holds up to 64KB
- MEDIUMTEXT holds up to 16MB
- LONGTEXT holds up to 4GB

Comment: Fully agree with this. I would also investigate whether all stories have an author entry on author_story and all author entries on author_story have a matching record on users. It seems logical that they should, and in which case the joins for these could also be changed to INNER JOINs.

Comment: Right, it should always be true that if a row exists in `author_story`, then it references an existing row in both `stories` and `users`.  If that's not true, then you have an orphaned row in `author_story` and that's an anomaly.  But you could easily have a row in `stories` with no row in `author_story`, therefore you need the outer join.  Converting the outer join to the `classifications` table is much more important, because it can give a clue to the optimizer to re-order the tables.

Comment: The indices changed the EXPLAIN plan considerably but strangely enough the optimizer had an epiphany because it started putting the classifications table first. Given that, putting classifications first had no impact on performance but I will keep it this way because it makes better sense. QUERY comparison & EXPLAIN: http://hastebin.com/hifokahuyo.m

Comment: @Kickstart, no, not "all stories have an author entry on author_story". But from Bill's explanation I take it that if all author_story entries have story/author records I can do an inner join. The performance was unchanged through the authors INNER JOIN but logically it makes sense so I'll update my query after some further testing.

Comment: For inner join on author_story and users, the QUERY & EXPLAIN: http://hastebin.com/delokuhoka.m

Comment: @BillKarwin, I updated the second code box once again, just now with explain, indexes and the new query and followed your suggestions for analyse + querying multiple times. Didn't know about GROUP BY NULL, nice trick.The ordering of stories is essential but I'll move that to app layer. The difference now with and without GROUP BY is 0.006 vs 0.015.

Comment: using ORDER BY NULL didn't get rid of the filesort by the way.

Comment: aleemb, surprised you don't have a author_stories record for all stories , but it was worth investigating. As @Meherzad suggested, you could use a straight_join to force the order of the join between stories and classifications, but fortunately it seems that MySQL has dealt with this correctly now.

Comment: Yeah, certain stories don't have authors, it's a client requirement unfortunately. The USING INDEX optimization is still not working, I am not sure why but overall am really happy with the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

As you are using MYSQL you can take advantage of [`Straight_join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

`STRAIGHT_JOIN forces the optimizer to join the tables in the order in which they are listed in the FROM clause. You can use this to speed up a query if the optimizer joins the tables in nonoptimal order`

Also one scope of improvement is in filtering the data of table `stories` as you only need data having status 1

So in the form clause instead of adding the whole `stories` table add the only the needed records as your query plan shows that there are `434792` rows and same for the `classification` table

```
FROM
   (SELECT 
       * 
   FROM
       STORIES
   WHERE 
       STORIES.status = 1) stories
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 
       * 
   FROM
       classifications
   WHERE
       classifications.`name` LIKE 'Home:Top%') classifications
ON stories.id = classifications.story_id
```

Also one more suggestion you can increase [`sort_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) as you are shown as `order by` and `group by`, but be careful increasing your buffer size as the size of the buffer increases for each session.

Also if it is possible you can order your records in your application if possible as you have mentioned removing the `order by` clause improves the takes only `1/6` part of the original time...

### **EDIT**

Add indexes to `image_story.image_id` for `image_story` table and `author_story.story_id` for `author_story` table as these columns are used for join

Also index on `images.position, images.id` has to be created as you are using it.

### **EDIT 16/4**

I think so you almost optimized your query seeing you update...

Still one place you can improve is using appropriate data type as BillKarwin has mentioned...
You can use **[`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html)** or **[`TINYINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)** type for columns like status and other which don'y have any scope of growth, it will help you to optimize your query performance and also storage performance of your table....

Hope this helps....

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but I am definitely missing something here. Adding the nested story (and even classification) select as you showed here slowed the query to the point where I had to abort it - http://hastebin.com/dilisusotu.sql

Comment: Seeing the explain plans seems that the index were not used properly try this query http://hastebin.com/yecohafeqi.sql.... In the attached query I have explicitly mentioned the compiler to use which index ans also used `straight_join` Hope it helps.... Thanks man for introducing me to such great site hastebin loved it.... :)

Comment: Still no luck with the query, you can see the EXPLAIN @ http://hastebin.com/nunuleviyo.rb -- the number of rows returned are very high. I tried changing the order arround but things were still very slow. Not sure why. (love hastebin too)

Answer (score 6):

Computing

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT classifications2.name SEPARATOR ';')
```

is probably the most time-consuming operation because `classifications` is a big table and the number of rows to work with is multiplied because of all the joins.

So I would recommend using a **temporary table** for that information.
Also, to avoid computing the LIKE condition twice (once for the temporary table and once for the "real" query), I would also create a temporary table for that.

Your original query, in a very simplified version (without the images and users table so that it's easier to read) is:

```
SELECT
    stories.*,
    count(DISTINCT comments.id) AS comments,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT classifications2.name ORDER BY 1 SEPARATOR ';' )
        AS classifications_name
FROM
    stories
    LEFT JOIN classifications
        ON stories.id = classifications.story_id
    LEFT JOIN classifications AS classifications2
        ON stories.id = classifications2.story_id
    LEFT JOIN comments
        ON stories.id = comments.story_id
WHERE
    classifications.`name` LIKE 'Home:Top%'
        AND stories.status = 1
GROUP BY stories.id
    ORDER BY stories.id, classifications.`name`, classifications.`positions`;
```

I would replace it with the following queries, with temporary tables `_tmp_filtered_classifications` (the ids of classifications with name LIKE Home:Top%') and `_tmp_classifications_of_story` (for each story id 'contained' in `_tmp_filtered_classifications`, all classification names):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_tmp_filtered_classifications`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_filtered_classifications
    SELECT id FROM classifications WHERE name LIKE 'Home:Top%';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_tmp_classifications_of_story`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_classifications_of_story ENGINE=MEMORY
    SELECT stories.id AS story_id, classifications2.name
        FROM 
        _tmp_filtered_classifications
        INNER JOIN classifications        
            ON _tmp_filtered_classifications.id=classifications.id
        INNER JOIN stories
            ON stories.id = classifications.story_id
        LEFT JOIN classifications AS classifications2
            ON stories.id = classifications2.story_id
        GROUP BY 1,2;

SELECT
    stories.*,
    count(DISTINCT comments.id) AS comments,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT classifications2.name ORDER BY 1 SEPARATOR ';')
        AS classifications_name
FROM
    _tmp_filtered_classifications
    INNER JOIN classifications        
        ON _tmp_filtered_classifications.id=classifications.id
    INNER JOIN stories
        ON stories.id = classifications.story_id
    LEFT JOIN _tmp_classifications_of_story AS classifications2
        ON stories.id = classifications2.story_id
    LEFT JOIN comments
        ON stories.id = comments.story_id
WHERE
    stories.status = 1
GROUP BY stories.id
    ORDER BY stories.id, classifications.`name`, classifications.`positions`;
```

Note that I added some more "order by" clauses to your query in order to check that both queries provide the same results (using diff).  I also changed `count(comments.id)` to `count(DISTINCT comments.id)` otherwise the number of comments the query computes is wrong (again, because of the joins that multiply the number of rows).

Comment: This definitely did result in performance improvements but they weren't consistent. Sometimes the query took twice as long (probably due to memory management or paging or something). I have posted an updated EXPLAIN plan based on some other improvements so now the only culprits are GROUP BY and ORDER BY. Thanks for the explanation though, it's something I will keep in mind for future optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the details of your data to experiment, but I do know that you should perform the operation first that will match the least amount of data and therefore eliminate the most amount of data for subsequent operations.

Depending on how complex your overall query is, you may not be able to re-order the operations in this way. However, you can perform two separate queries, where the first one just eliminates data that is definitely not going to be needed, and then feeds its result to the second query. Someone else suggested using temporary tables, and that is a good way to handle that situation.

If you need any clarification of this strategy, let me know.

** Update: A similar tactic, used when each operation matches approximately the same percentage of data as the other operations, is to time each operation separately, and then run the operation first that uses the least amount of time. Some searching operations are quicker than others, and the fastest ones should be first if all other factors are equal. This way, the slower searching operations will have less data to work with, and the overall result will be higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the `LIKE` condition is the worst thing on your request.
Are you sure you have to do this?

4 steps :

1. Create a `IsHomeTop` bool indexed column on the `classifications` table
2. Run `UPDATE classifications SET IsTopHome = 1 WHERE NAME LIKE 'Home:Top%'`
3. Run your initial query with `WHERE classifications.IsTopHome == 1`
4. Enjoy

Your query is too critical for letting the `LIKE` operator decrease your performance.
And if `stories` is updated a lot, I don't think it is the case of your `classifications` table. So give you a chance and eradicate the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways you can attempt here:

```
1) create covering index on classifications.`name`
```

You can speed up the query by creating covering index .

A covering index refers to the case when all fields selected in a query are covered by an index, in that case InnoDB (not MyISAM) will never read the data in the table, but only use the data in the index, significantly speeding up the select.

CREATE TABLE `classifications` (
KEY `class_name` (`name`,...all columns)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

2) instead of `classifications.name LIKE 'Home:Top%'` 
use `locate('Home:Top',classifications.name)`